# How to break forEach loop inside "let" lambda?

Tags: kotlin

To optimize my loop i need to break it if my "if" construction is true. For example:

```
radioGroup.forEach { button ->
     button.color?.let {
         if (it = myColor) {
            println("Color fits!")
            /** Here i need to break radioGroup.forEach loop because i found color */
         }
     }
}
```

But i can call "break" only inside a loop. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to the other answers here is to use:

```
radioGroup.firstOrNull { button -> button.color == myColor }?.let {
    println("Color fits!")
    //"it" is the matched button here
}
```

What's nice is that inside the `let` you will have access to the matched button as the `it` variable.

Comment: Why should we use `firstOrNull` instead of `first`?

Comment: @SoulReaver313 the difference with `first` is that `first` will throw an exception if there is no match at all. `firstOrNull` will return `null` instead, and so in this example it won't even go in the `let` block because of the `?` before the `.let`

Comment: I can't use `firstOrNull` for radioGroup. Should i get array of views inside it first?

Comment: @SoulReaver313 ah I assumed radioGroup already was a list or array because I saw you used `forEach`.  I guess you would need that then. I'm not entirely sure but I think `radioGroup.allViews.firstOrNull` would work for that

Comment: `radioGroup.children.firstOrNull` should be it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use run block with label name and stop it with your condition, for example

```
run loop@ {
    radioGroup.forEach { button ->
        button.color?.let {
            if (it = myColor) {
                println("Color fits!")
                return@loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it good for performance? I mean it will be better than just iterate through whole loop?

Comment: I think in your case it can be done in one loop and break keyword will work well, but in some other cases like 2 or more nested loop label will be easier and no need to add some extra variables

Comment: The problem is that i can't break my loop inside "if" statement but i need to break it only if my statement is true :/

Comment: I mean to achive this using normal loop like this `for(button in radioGroup.allViews) {
            if (button.color != null && button.color = myColor) {
                break
            }
        }`

Comment: looks too Java styled :D

Comment: yes :D it look the same like java here

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to achieve that:

1. You can use return with a label:

```
run loop@{
    radioGroup.forEach { button ->
        println(button)
        button.color?.let {
            if (it == myColor) {
                println("Color fits!")
                return@loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. You can create a function and use *return* keyword something like that:

```
fun fits(radioGroup: List<Button>, myColor: String): Boolean {
    radioGroup.forEach { button ->
        button.color?.let {
            if (it == myColor) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

3. Or just get rid of returns at all:

```kotlin
if (radioGroup.any { button -> button.color == myColor }) {
    println("Color fits!")
}
```

Comment: First example does not really break from the loop.

Comment: @broot Yeah, sorry for that. I fixed my code in the answer